# Problem trying to run Assembly in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to run some assembly code in Visual Studio 2012 and call it in C just for testing purposes. As I have no experience writing assembly code I have no idea what is going wrong, so I would greatly appreciate some help!

I get the following errors trying to compile the code:

```
Error   5   error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\callee.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Tacallee.asm" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets 49  5   ProjetoASM
Error   2   error A2206: missing operator in expression C:\Users\Suporte\Desktop\ASM\ProjetoASM\ProjetoASM\callee.asm   18  1   ProjetoASM
Error   3   error A2206: missing operator in expression C:\Users\Suporte\Desktop\ASM\ProjetoASM\ProjetoASM\callee.asm   21  1   ProjetoASM
Error   4   error A2206: missing operator in expression C:\Users\Suporte\Desktop\ASM\ProjetoASM\ProjetoASM\callee.asm   8   1   ProjetoASM
Error   1   error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size C:\Users\Suporte\Desktop\ASM\ProjetoASM\ProjetoASM\callee.asm   15  1   ProjetoASM
```

And the Assembly code:

```
PUBLIC hello_from_asm
EXTERN puts:PROC

.model flat

.data

    msg    db 'Hello, world!',0xa    
    len    equ $ - msg

.code

hello_from_asm PROC
        mov     edx,len                  
        mov     ecx,msg                         
        mov     ebx,1                            
        mov     eax,4                         
        int     0x80                          

        mov     eax,1                            
        int     0x80                              
hello_from_asm ENDP

END
```

This was supposed to output a "Hello, world!", so any other ideas that might work are also welcome.

C code for completeness:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void hello_from_asm();

int main(){
    printf("Hello from C");
    hello_from_asm();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int     0x80` is the 32-bit Linux system-cal ABI.  That's never going to work as part of a native Windows program. The parts you copied from some NASM example are still in NASM syntax, which seems to be what MASM is complaining about.  e.g. I don't think MASM allows `0xa`, only `0aH` for hex numeric literals.  And in MASM, `mov     ecx,msg` means `mov     ecx, [msg]`.  Not that it matters, because `int 0x80` will just fault under Windows, so it doesn't matter whether you have a pointer or 4 bytes of ASCII data in ECX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those detailed MASM error messages tell it all.

> ```
> mov     ecx,msg
> ```

You're required to use MASM style. The above instruction tries to load the first byte of *msg* in a 32-bit register. That's the "size mismatch" error.
What you need is loading the address of *msg* in `ECX`. Use

```
mov ecx, offset msg
```

The other errors might be about not recognizing the `0x` hexadecimal prefix. Try using the `h` hexadecimal suffix instead. (`0Ah`, `80h`)

The above is easy enough to change, and your code will assemble fine. However don't run it because the `int 80h` instruction is a Linux system call that is not going to work on Visual Studio 2012 (Windows).

Comment: I think it's important to mention that once you get this to assemble, it will just fault on `int 80h` because this is Windows, not Linux.  And `mov   ecx,msg` could equally be described as trying to load the first *4* bytes of `msg` (based on the register implying an operand-size), which is why MASM will complain about operand-size mismatch because `symbol: db` also implies an operand-size for references to that symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Example 32 bit Visual Studio | Masm program to print "Hello World". I included the most common directives. "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib" is used for VS2015 and later, since printf and scanf were changed to be inlined with the output of the C compiler. You may not need it for VS2012.

```
        .686p                   ;enable instructions
        .xmm                    ;enable instructions
        .model flat,c           ;use C naming convention (stdcall is default)

;       include C libraries
        includelib      msvcrtd
        includelib      oldnames
        includelib      legacy_stdio_definitions.lib    ;for scanf, printf, ...

        .data                   ;initialized data
pfstr   db      "Hello world!",0dh,0ah,0
        .data?                  ;uinitialized data
        .stack  4096            ;stack (optional, linker will default)

        .code                   ;code 
        extrn   printf:near
        public  main

main    proc

        push    offset pfstr    ; 32-bit mode uses stack args
        call    printf
        add     esp,4           ; cdecl is caller-pops

        xor     eax,eax         ; return 0
        ret
main    endp

        end
```

Comment: `printf` is never stdcall; it takes a variable number of args.  Your last change made the comment wrong / misleading.  Yes `stdcall` also uses stack args, but the calling convention being used to call printf in 32-bit mode is `cdecl`.  `stdcall` wouldn't use `add esp,4` after the call.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I edited my answer. My confusion is due to 64 bit mode calling convention, in which case the first 2 parameters to printf are in rcx and rdx. I was thinking there could be a 32 bit fast call version of printf that could take its first two arguments in ecx and edx, even though it probably would result in slightly slower code, since there aren't as many registers in 32 bit mode.

Comment: Oh, yeah unfortunately 32-bit `fastcall` is callee-pops, so it can't be used for printf.  (ISO C requires printf to ignore extra unused args that the format string doesn't tell it about).  The 64-bit calling convention is caller-pops so it can work for variadic functions, and can pass the first 4 args in RCX, RDX, R8, R9 if they're integer / pointer.

Comment: @PeterCordes - and adding to the confusion is VS2015 and later now inlining printf and scanf in C/C++ compiled code (you can see this if you output the C/C++ generated assembly code). Fortunately, there the legacy library, at least through VS2019.